# Autocorrelation of a signal with gaps

Tags: autocorrelation

I am trying to find the analytic expression of the autocorrelation function for a signal $X(t)$ which is defined as follows.

- $X(t = 0) = 1$
- At random times jumps to $X(t) = 0$ happen

  - The jump probability in each infinitesimal time-step is $\Gamma dt$
- After the jump the signal stays at $0$ for time $\tau$
- Then the signal jumps back to $1$

Do you know how or even if it is possible to calculate the autocorrelation function of such a signal?

The signal should describe the following scenario:

Imagine you have a house with a window. In front of the window there is a railway where trains can pass. Each train takes a fixed time $\tau$ to pass the window and trains arrive at random times. Assume that I am pointing a laser across the railway trough the window. If I can see the laser $X(t) = 1$ else the laser is hidden by the train and $X(t) = 0$. I want to calculate the autocorrelation function of such a signal.

Comment: Is $\tau$ fixed and deterministic?

Comment: To little informations about your signal to give specific answer, but you might find this useful: [Random Rectangular Pulse Train ACF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33600147/Rect_pulse_train_ACF.pdf)

Comment: @jojek What kind of additional information is needed to give a specific answer?

Comment: @Matt L. $\tau$ is fixed and some real number. What do you mean by deterministic?

Comment: @physicsGuy: Most importantly please answer Matt's question - it's crucial for understanding.

Comment: @jojek I posted it a second before your comment. I'm kind of new to signal processing, so it could well be that I need to make a better definition of my process. I added a short paragraph to my question that gives a 'implementation' of my signal, I hope that helps you understand my problem.

Comment: @physicsGuy: Now description contains great example and everything is clear!

Comment: OK, so $\tau$ is a fixed constant. By 'deterministic' I meant 'not random'.

Comment: @physicsGuy: But now that I have read your edited questions (the train example), it is necessary that all trains have the same length and travel at the same speed for $\tau$ to be a fixed constant, right? (Or longer trains need to go faster than shorter ones ...)

Comment: Yes, that would be a requirement and might not be realistic. Think of it is an example, so that we know we talk of the same things because I am new to the field of signal processing. I want to avoid that we get stuck in definitions, which I found out can easily happen if people of different fields talk to each other.

Comment: Apart from all the other matters discussed in the comments, a very important issue is "What is meant by `At random times jumps to...`?"  There is no such thing as a random number, or a positive random number, unless the _distribution_ is specified: the common response that "random means that all values are equally likely to be chosen" **does not work.** For example, in the link pointed out by @jojek, the random time is uniformly distributed on $[-T/2,T/2]$. For the problem posed here, "random means $U(0,T)$ gives vastly different results than "random means $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$".

Comment: It might be fruitful to consider your signal as a convolution of a boxcar (rectangular) filter with a signal of Dirac delta pulses. The time between delta pulses can be no less than $\tau$

Comment: @MarkBorgerding Thank you, that could be a way to do it

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right, I have to add that the jumps occur at a rate $\Gamma$. Assume that at $t = 0$ the signal is $X(0)=1$. Then the next jump to $0$ occurs at time $t$ with probability $1 - \exp(-\Gamma t)$.

Comment: This means that in each infinitesimal time-step a jump can happen with prob. $\Gamma t$.